# WinAPI. Check if window resizing has been finished

Tags: c++, winapi

I've got C++ application (used for share application's window via network). I need to update application's area on client side when it's size was changed on server side. For this purpose once in a period of time I call `GetWindowPos` to check if the window was resized. But I don't want to send the info when the window is in resizing state and send the info only when resizing is completed. I noticed that on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 `GetWindowPos` returns same values when the window is in resizing state, however on Windows 7 it returns different values when the window is in resizing state. So the question is how to understand if window is in resizing state?

**UPD**: Implementation of `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` - `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` variant

```
void WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow::SetMsgHook()
{
    m_pThis = this;
    m_msgHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, MsgPoc, NULL, 0);
}
```

Static function that call non-static method of the class:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow::MsgPoc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (m_pThis != nullptr)
    {
        return m_pThis->GetMsgProcHook(code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Hook function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow::GetMsgProcHook(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    MSG* lpmsg = (MSG*)lParam;
    if (lpmsg->hwnd != m_windowHandle)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    if (lpmsg->message == WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE && !m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        m_isWindowResizing = true;
    }
    else if (lpmsg->message == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE && m_isWindowResizing)
    {
        m_isWindowResizing = false;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

`m_pThis` and `m_msgHook` are static class members:

```
WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow* WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow::m_pThis = nullptr;
HHOOK WindowsDisplayHelperMasterWindow::m_msgHook = NULL;
```

And here is the check itself:

```
if (!m_displayMode.IsEqualGeometry(displayMode) && !m_isWindowResizing)
{
    DUMPER_DEBUG("DS_ERROR_MODE_CHANGED");
    return DS_ERROR_MODE_CHANGED; // depending on this value server asks client to update application's window area
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A window receives a [`WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-entersizemove) message, after it has entered the moving and sizing modal loop. A window receives a [`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-exitsizemove) message, after it has exited the moving or sizing modal loop.

If you monitor those two messages, you know when a window is in moving and sizing state.

Comment: I updated my initial code with implementation of your variant. Did you mean something like I implemented?

Comment: Unfortunately, hook these messages is not my variant. Are there any other ways to check if application's windows is resizing?

Comment: If you don't understand the implications of using a global hook, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) again: *"All global hook functions **must be in libraries**."*

Comment: That is why this solution is not suitable for me and that is why I'm interesting if there any other variants to check if window is in resizing state.

Comment: There isn't. And it's quite dubious why a solution that works for everyone wouldn't be suitable for you.